# AudioKit Synth One crashes in offline render to MIDI

Tags: swift, audiokit

I have a customized `renderToFile` function that I'm using for offline rendering from midi, but when I try to render using a skinless version of Synth One (we're just using presets, in the initial release of our app), I get a crash in: `S1NoteState::startNoteHelper`.

[UPDATE] Here is my complete `renderToFile` function -- basically the same as AudioKit's, but adding in a check for midi events occurring in the time of the buffer being written. Also, I use an AKLazyTap to fill my buffer with samples from the instrument. That buffer is then written to a file in the same way as AK's original implementation.

```
public func renderToFile(_ audioFile: AVAudioFile, maximumFrameCount: AVAudioFrameCount, duration: Double, prerender: (() -> Void)? = nil) throws {
        guard duration >= 0 else {
            throw NSError(domain: "AVAudioEngine ext", code: 1,
                          userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Seconds needs to be a positive value"])
        }
        var duration = duration
        let conductor = Conductor.sharedInstance

        try AKTry {
            // Engine can't be running when switching to offline render mode.
            if AudioKit.engine.isRunning { AudioKit.engine.stop() }
            try AudioKit.engine.enableManualRenderingMode(.offline, format: audioFile.processingFormat, maximumFrameCount: maximumFrameCount)

            // This resets the sampleTime of offline rendering to 0.
            AudioKit.engine.reset()
            try AudioKit.engine.start()
        }

        guard let buffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: AudioKit.engine.manualRenderingFormat, frameCapacity: AudioKit.engine.manualRenderingMaximumFrameCount) else {
            throw NSError(domain: "AVAudioEngine ext", code: 1,
                          userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Couldn't create buffer in renderToFile"])
        }
        // We'll try using a (local) tap to fill the buffer with samples from the Conductor's current instrument.
        let tap = AKLazyTap(node: conductor.instrumentBooster.avAudioNode)

        // This is for users to prepare the nodes for playing, i.e player.play()
        prerender?()
        let scheduledEvents: [AKMIDIEvent] = conductor.eventsForOfflineRender
        let noteOffs = scheduledEvents.filter { 128 ... 159 ~= $0.internalData[0] }.filter { $0.internalData[2] == 0 }
        let lastOff = noteOffs.sorted { $0.position!.seconds < $1.position!.seconds }.last!.position!.seconds
        duration = lastOff

        // Render until file contains >= target samples
        let targetSamples = AVAudioFramePosition(duration * AudioKit.engine.manualRenderingFormat.sampleRate)
        while audioFile.framePosition < targetSamples {
            // The range, in frames, to render for this window.
            let framesToRender = min(buffer.frameCapacity, AVAudioFrameCount( targetSamples - audioFile.framePosition))
            let windowSampleStart = audioFile.framePosition
            let windowSampleEnd = windowSampleStart + AVAudioFramePosition(framesToRender)

            var eventsInThisBuffer: [AKMIDIEvent] = []
            // Check whether the window represented by (inTimeStamp + inNumberFrames) contains any scehduledEvents. If so, pass those events to the instrument's music device (AudioUnit) during this callback.
            for event in scheduledEvents {
                if windowSampleStart ..< windowSampleEnd ~= Int64(event.position!.samples) {
                    eventsInThisBuffer.append(event)
                }
            }
            // Then pass the collected events to the conductor's current instrument.
            for event in eventsInThisBuffer {
                try conductor.handle(event: event)
            }

            var firstSampleTime = AudioTimeStamp()
            tap?.fillNextBuffer(buffer, timeStamp: &firstSampleTime)

            let status = try AudioKit.engine.renderOffline(framesToRender, to: buffer)
            switch status {
            case .success:
                try audioFile.write(from: buffer)
            case .cannotDoInCurrentContext:
                AKLog("renderToFile cannotDoInCurrentContext")
                continue
            case .error, .insufficientDataFromInputNode:
                throw NSError(domain: "AVAudioEngine ext", code: 1,
                              userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "renderToFile render error"])
            @unknown default:
                fatalError("Unknown render result")
            }
        }

        try AKTry {
            AudioKit.engine.stop()
            AudioKit.engine.disableManualRenderingMode()
            AudioKit.engine.reset()
            try AudioKit.engine.start()
        }
    }
```

We also have an instance of AKMIDISampler, which correctly writes to a file using this method, with the one bug/exception that it also includes a mysterious sine wave in the output (any thoughts on that appreciated!). I've seen other posts about the sine wave here on SO, but the fixes mentioned there haven't yet worked in my situation.

But as to the AK Synth One crash, I'm wondering whether there's something particular about manual rendering mode that's messing things up? I've tried enabling zombies, but no useful information is given. The backtrace (which is pretty brief) doesn't reveal anything significant that I can see:

```
* thread #14, queue = 'renderQueue', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
  * frame #0: 0x000000010265c910 Spliqs`S1NoteState::startNoteHelper(this=0x000000010b515730, noteNumber=48, velocity=59, frequency=130.812775) at S1NoteState.mm:105
    frame #1: 0x000000010266e34c Spliqs`S1DSPKernel::turnOnKey(this=0x00000001090e4f90, noteNumber=48, velocity=59, frequency=130.812775) at S1DSPKernel+toggleKeys.mm:85
    frame #2: 0x0000000102661778 Spliqs`S1DSPKernel::startNote(this=0x00000001090e4f90, noteNumber=48, velocity=59, frequency=130.812775) at S1DSPKernel+startStopNotes.mm:45
    frame #3: 0x0000000102658640 Spliqs`::-[S1AudioUnit startNote:velocity:frequency:](self=0x00000001090e4e00, _cmd="startNote:velocity:frequency:", note='0', velocity=';', frequency=130.812775) at S1AudioUnit.mm:98
    frame #4: 0x0000000102c1f500 Spliqs`AKSynthOne.play(noteNumber=48, velocity=59, frequency=130.81277465820313, self=0x0000000281aa40a0) at AKSynthOne.swift:223
    frame #5: 0x0000000102a8db7c Spliqs`Conductor.handleMIDI(data1=144, data2=48, data3=59, self=0x000000010811ccf0) at Conductor.swift:340
    frame #6: 0x0000000102a8d1ac Spliqs`Conductor.handle(event=AudioKit.AKMIDIEvent @ 0x000000016df0e830, self=0x000000010811ccf0) at Conductor.swift:322
    frame #7: 0x0000000102c5861c Spliqs`SQRenderManager.renderToFile(audioFile=0x0000000283be61a0, maximumFrameCount=512, duration=18, prerender=0x0000000102c57064 Spliqs`partial apply forwarder for closure #1 () -> () in Spliqs.SQRenderManager.offlineRender(_: SpliqsLib.Spliq, completion: () -> ()) -> () at <compiler-generated>, self=0x00000002812ba920) at SQRenderManager.swift:167
    frame #8: 0x0000000102c56be0 Spliqs`SQRenderManager.offlineRender(spliq=0x0000000112642a90, completion=0x0000000102c60b80 Spliqs`closure #1 () -> () in closure #1 () -> () in closure #1 (RxSwift.Event<Spliqs.TimedWatchableEvent>) -> () in Spliqs.SQRenderManager.init(withModule: Spliqs.SequencerModule) -> Spliqs.SQRenderManager at SQRenderManager.swift:527, self=0x00000002812ba920) at SQRenderManager.swift:101
    frame #9: 0x0000000102c60b68 Spliqs`closure #1 in closure #1 in SQRenderManager.init(self=0x00000002812ba920, spliq=0x0000000112642a90) at SQRenderManager.swift:527
    frame #10: 0x0000000102685cdc Spliqs`thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () at <compiler-generated>:0
    frame #11: 0x0000000107f0f260 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
    frame #12: 0x0000000107f107e0 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 20
    frame #13: 0x0000000107f13cf8 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_continuation_pop + 560
    frame #14: 0x0000000107f130e0 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 632
    frame #15: 0x0000000107f21a84 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_root_queue_drain + 352
    frame #16: 0x0000000107f2248c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_worker_thread2 + 144
    frame #17: 0x00000002291a3b50 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 468
    frame #18: 0x00000002291a9dc4 libsystem_pthread.dylib`start_wqthread + 4
```

The Synth One instance and our sampler are both owned by a Conductor, following a similar design to the public release of Synth One, with the one difference that our Conductor handles midi events directly, using the same method employed by AKMIDINode (i.e., using `enableMIDI` and `handleMIDI`). Other than switching to/from manual rendering mode, I'm really not sure what's going on.

I will mention that I do find AK's internal operations a bit mysterious, as we still have issues with, for example, starting and stopping the engine, which will uncover the same problems -- e.g., the mystery sine wave and crashing when using AK Synth One.

Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

Comment: Though I wouldn't consider it a "fix", I can get it to work if I basically recreate synth—i.e., reinstantiate Synth One, set the delegate, output, etc. Not surprising, I suppose, but it seems like overkill, for sure.